# Entityform is spanning the full width of the browser. Well beyond page margins

Tags: entities, theming

http://chesapeakeregional.com/volunteer#overlay-context=volunteers

I did not create the form, nor the site, nor do I have any knowledge of Drupal. But somehow I got assigned to make this form fit within the normal width of the site and I'm clueless. If I'm not being clear, I basically just want to wrap the form with a div about 1140px wide and center it horizontally in the browser.

Please help!

Comment: This is a CSS issue really. You should be able to inspect the page with Firebug or developer window and find the element that wraps around the content, then change the element's width in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the somewhat flawed structured and logic of the theme. The best solution to this would have been to restructure the theme and apply the styles for the `container` class, which handles most of the content layout, to a wrapper in the `page.tpl.php` template so that all pages get the same layout no matter content.

However, as the theme is as it is, and you don't have much Drupal knowledge I would instead recommend to apply the "container" class to the form element, or wrap the form in a div with that class. Unfortunately you can't do that in the UI.

The fastest and easiest way to fix this is to add the class to the form using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

In your `/sites/all/themes/chesapeake/template.php` file, add:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function chesapeake_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'volunteer_form_entityform_edit_form') {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'container';
  }
}
```

And then clear the cache at `Configuration > Development > Performance`. That should add the "container" class to the form and display the page correctly.

Comment: Drupal adds a lot of wrappers etc in various templates etc. Adding an extra one for this issue alone seems very much redundant and not in the spirit of drupal templating. Longboardnode's comment seems like the way to go.

Comment: @SurangaPanagamuwaGamage No, that would be a lot more work. The use of the "container" class is in line with how the site is built so that is the best option unless you want to redo all the CSS including media queries etc. along with all child element styling and whatnot just for this form. An alternative solution would be to add the existing form class alongside the "container" class wherever it's used in the CSS, but I don't see that as easier nor better.

Comment: In this case I admit your way is probably the fastest. But I still feel this is a bit of an iffy patch to something that is structurally unsound in a templating logic. However if you make a small edit on your answer I'll remove the downvote because it's indeed unwarrented on second inspection of the site.

Comment: Yes, adding the class is not the best solution, but it's an easy enough solution to explain and implement. Personally I would have restructured the theme, but taken in consideration that OP have no knowledge of Drupal I didn't see that as a solution in this case. That said, I have expanded on my answer.